# Does emails having UNKNOWN_PARAMETER_VALUE contain a virus? Or is it a MIME problem?

Tags: email

I developed a program that sends emails (with attachments to clients). Now, some of the clients are asking what they should do with the emails with `UNKNOWN_PARAMETER_VALUE.DAT`? I'm quite sure that I've not sent attachments with those names. Only a few of the clients have received attachments with this. Is this a virus? If not, is this a MIME problem (FYI, some attachments have Chinese filename, I'm not sure if this might be a probable cause).

Comment: Post the complete headers and mailparts your program generates. Nobody can help you with a vague question like this one.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a virus. At least it's listed [here](http://koti.mbnet.fi/pattaya1/testitulokset_30092006.htm).